# I cannot get the data from my snapshot to load into my tableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-application

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()
 ref.child("Clubs").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in
        print("clubs: \(snapshot)")

        if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
        print("myClubs: \(childSnapshot)")
```

From this point, i am unable to get the "name" and "bannerImage" to load into my tableView

```
if let clubName = childSnapshot["name"] as? String, let banner = childSnapshot["bannerImage"] as? String {
   print(clubName)
   print(banner)

   let club = Club(name: clubName, image: banner)
   print("new club success: \(club)")

   self.nightClubs.append(club)
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: User Interface should be updated on the main thread. So reload tableview in the main thread.

Comment: i added it on the main thread but its still not loading up :(

Comment: could you please post your tableview datasource and delegate method code.

Comment: Please update to include your database structure. You can get this structure using the Export JSON setting in the Firebase console under the three dots.

Answer (score 1):

Use  this:-

```
 ref = Database.database().reference()

   ref.child("Clubs").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print("clubs: \(snapshot)")

    if(snapshot.exists()) {
        let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray

        for obj in array {
            let snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot
            if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print("myClubs: \(childSnapshot)")

                if let clubName = childSnapshot["name"] as? String, let banner = childSnapshot["bannerImage"] as? String {
                    print(clubName)
                    print(banner)

                    let club = Club(name: clubName, image: banner)
                    print("new club success: \(club)")
                    self.nightClubs.append(club)
                }
            }
        }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot! The code works fine but now anytime i make a change in the database it duplicates my cells, applying the change to a whole new set of cells

Comment: remove all objects from nightClubs  array after this line :-      let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray